# Spotify AlarmClock

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to build a AlarmClock for Spotify and make Spotify play a song when the alarm is triggered.

The clock is working so all I need know is to get the song playing then the function is triggered. How can I write that?

I wanna use a Spotify Url for making it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [Player](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/f19ff300f8.html) object.

```
models.player.play("spotify:track:6JEK0CvvjDjjMUBFoXShNZ");
```